# Input type attribute breaks angular form Validators

Tags: angular

I just realized my error messaging broke and had no idea why. It turns out that adding type="number" or any valid html type attribute, does not trigger error messages (minLength or maxLength but have not tested others).

component:

```
createForm() {
this.shortForm = this.fb.group({
  firstName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(50) ]], 
  lastName: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(1), Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  primaryAddrZip: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(5), Validators.maxLength(5)] ]      
})
```

template:

```
 <md-input-container>
    <input
      type="number"
      formControlName="primaryAddrZip"
      mdInput placeholder="Zip code"
      data-testing="zip"
      (keypress)="numbersOnlyValidation($event, 'zip'); maxLength($event, 5)"
      (paste)="$event.preventDefault()"
    >
    <md-error data-testing="zip-req" *ngIf="shortForm.get('primaryAddrZip').hasError('required') && shortForm.get('primaryAddrZip').touched">
      Zip code is required
    </md-error>
    <md-error data-testing="zip-min-five-digits" *ngIf="shortForm.get('primaryAddrZip').hasError('minlength') && shortForm.get('primaryAddrZip').touched">
      Minimum of 5 characters .  <!--WILL NOT TRIGGER-->
    </md-error>
  </md-input-container>
```

Is this a know bug or am I using the Validator incorrectly?

Comment: Per your Form Builder, you defined primaryAddrZip a string (primaryAddrZip: [''......). Change that to a number may be?

Comment: it is not yet implemented in the material

Comment: @Rama How would I change it to a number?  The single quotes after the bracket are for the value of the form field. I think?

Comment: @Aravind I dont think this is a material issue. The functionality is angular validator based and regular *ngIf in the template.

Comment: @Anthony you might be correct. Changing that single quotes to 0 did not change the behavior. May be create a plunker with your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "by design" in HTML 5.

`maxLength` is for strings. This is from the MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-maxlength

> maxlength If the value of the type attribute is text, email, search,
>   password, tel, or url, this attribute specifies the maximum number of
>   characters (in Unicode code points) that the user can enter. For other
>   control types, it is ignored.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know angular validators leveraged HTML 5 attribute rules.